# Workflow: how to save customizations in git when the base app updates?

Tags: git, version-control, workflow, upgrade

There is a web app installed on many servers. Each server contains some customization and configuration on top of the base app, such as themes and custom views. When the base app gets upgraded, the customization needs to be checked and possibly updated.

I want to maintain a list of changes by making a git repo out of the app and commits out of the customization, but what would I do if the base app needs to be updated and the customization migrated to the new version?

I can check the commit list to see which files have been changed, but can I do something else that would help the process?

This will be my first time using git; so far I've only used subversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to maintain the base app in masters and the customizations in server branches so branches `master`, `server_a`,`server_b` etc.

Then when you release a new version you could [rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) the server branches (`git checkout server_a` then `git rebase master`)  on the new version in master, do the necessary changes (resolve conflicts, make adaptations) and release each server branch to the respective server (`git push server_a server_a_repository`).

Branches would look like:

```
   H sever_a
  /
-A-B-C-D-E-F-G- Master
 \
  I server_b
```

rebase

```
               H' sever_a
              /
-A-B-C-D-E-F-G- Master
              \
               I' server_b
```

From the git rebase page:

> It works by going to the common ancestor of the two branches (the one you’re on and the one you’re rebasing onto), getting the diff introduced by each commit of the branch you’re on, saving those diffs to temporary files, resetting the current branch to the same commit as the branch you are rebasing onto, and finally applying each change in turn. Figure 3-29 illustrates this process.

So basically it tries to apply your customization commits (`H` and `I`) as if they were made after the new commit `G`. And it does this by doing exactly what you want to do by hand (get all changes that were made on master and squish them in before the customizations are applied, showing you everywhere it finds conflicts on the way).

Comment: This sounds excellent! I must try this in practice for a while to get the hang of it, but it certainly sounds like what I want. Thanks!